# Read XML from Memory<byte>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a `Memory<byte>` that holds binary data for an XML element. I want to read the XML element into an `XElement` object, but this seems easier than at first sight. When using a `byte[]`, I would do something like this:

```
public static XElement GetXElementFromByteArray(byte[] buffer)
{
  using var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
  using var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream);

  return XElement.Load(xmlReader);
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot create a `Stream` object from a `Memory<T>` or `Span<T>` object and `XmlReader` requires a stream object. Of course, I can convert the `Memory<byte>` to a byte-array, but this will copy the data and the goal for my optimization is to reduce collections.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a pre-canned `Stream` implementation (or `XmlReader` implementation) that will work conveniently from a `Memory<byte>`. If the intent is to use `MemoryStream`, then perhaps the best thing is to *try* and get it as an array, and **if it isn't**, force a pooled copy:

```cs
ArraySegment<byte> segment = default;
bool leased = false;
try
{
    if (!MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray<byte>(memory, out segment))
    {
        var arr = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(memory.Length);
        memory.CopyTo(arr);
        segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(arr, 0, memory.Length);
        leased = true;
    }
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(segment.Array, segment.Offset, segment.Count))
    {
        // ... your usage goes here!
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(ms))
        {
            return XElement.Load(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    if (leased) ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(segment.Array);
}
```

The alternative is to create a new `Stream` implementation that works against `Memory<byte>`. That's a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a custom stream that seems to work, but I was wondering if there is an "official" implementation. I understand that this will only work for `Memory<byte>` and not for the generic type, but often memory access is done one a byte-basis.

This is my implementation:

```
public class ReadonlyMemByteStream : Stream
{
    private readonly ReadOnlyMemory<byte> _buffer;
    private int _offset;

    public ReadonlyMemByteStream(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> buffer)
    {
        _buffer = buffer;
        _offset = 0;
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        // NOP
    }

    public override int ReadByte()
    {
        return _buffer.Span[_offset++];
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var bufferLength = _buffer.Length - _offset;
        if (count > bufferLength)
            count = bufferLength;
        _buffer.Span.Slice(_offset).CopyTo(new Span<byte>(buffer, offset, count));
        _offset += count;
        return count;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        switch (origin)
        {
            case SeekOrigin.Begin:
                _offset = (int)offset;
                break;
            case SeekOrigin.Current:
                _offset += (int)offset;
                break;
            case SeekOrigin.End:
                _offset = _buffer.Length + (int)offset;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(origin), origin, null);
        }
        return _offset;
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanSeek => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override long Length => _buffer.Length;

    public override long Position
    {
        get => _offset;
        set => _offset = (int)value;
    }
}

public class MemByteStream : ReadonlyMemByteStream
{
    private readonly Memory<byte> _buffer;

    public MemByteStream(Memory<byte> buffer) : base(buffer)
    {
        _buffer = buffer;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        new Span<byte>(buffer, offset, count).CopyTo(_buffer.Span.Slice((int)Position));
        Position += count;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => true;
}
```

Comment: looks reasonable; you might want range validation in `Seek` and `Position` (the `set`). You might also might want to implement `WriteByte` in the `MemByteStream`, and for performance : note that in recent runtimes (perhaps just netcoreapp2.1 and above?) there are overloads of `Read[Async]` and `Write[Async]` that take span/memory/etc

Comment: Adding the `Span<T>` overrides is a good idea. I'm using spans internally already, so that may save some extra cycles. I'm not checking boundaries on purpose. The underlying classes do and I don't want to do excessive checking (due to CPU constraints). Async methods are not important for my use-case.